# Truffle is compiling projects from wrong folder

Tags: javascript, solidity, truffle

Very weird behavior from truffle:

```js
kaneda@motoko:~/farmsv1$ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
✔ Fetching solc version list from solc-bin. Attempt #1
Error: Could not find @uniswap/v2-periphery/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV2Router02.sol from any sources; imported from /home/kaneda/shuttle-farms/contracts/ShuttleToken.sol
```

As you can see, I'm in a directory called `~/farmsv1` while truffle is compiling contracts in `~/shuttle-farms`

I tried to move `farmsv1` to other directories, the same thing happened, also tried using `npx truffle compile`, but it still compiles the contracts from another directory.

Here is my truffle config that is exactly same for other project:

```js
const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
const fs = require('fs');
const mnemonic = fs.readFileSync(".secret").toString().trim();

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*",
    },
    testnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s2.binance.org:8545`),
      network_id: 97,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      networkCheckTimeout: 100000000,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
    bsc: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org`),
      network_id: 56,
      confirmations: 10,
      timeoutBlocks: 200,
      skipDryRun: true
    },
  },


  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.6.12",
    }
  }
}
```

*Note, they are cloned from same repository but from different branches, is there any correlation here that might be messing up truffle?*

Comment: I have the same error. Did you fix this?